# Instantaneous drift of a stochastic process

Tags: convergence-divergence, asymptotics, random-variables

Let $\mu_t$ and $\sigma_t$ be strictly positive bounded predictable processes and $W_t$ a Wiener process. 
Consider for $\Delta>0$

$$
X_{\Delta} = \int_0^{\Delta}\mu_s\,ds+\int_0^{\Delta}\sigma_s\,dWs
$$

and

$$
Q_{\Delta} =\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\frac{X_{\Delta}-\mu_0\,\Delta}{\sigma_0\,\sqrt{\Delta}}. & \text{ if }\Delta>0\\
1 & \text{ if }\Delta=0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

If I am not wrong I can write

$$
\int_0^{\Delta}\mu_s\,ds = \mu_0\,\Delta+o_P(\Delta),\quad \int_0^{\Delta}\sigma_s\,dWs = \sigma_0\,\sqrt{\Delta}+o_P(\sqrt{\Delta})
$$
whence for $\Delta>0$ 
$$
Q_{\Delta} = 1+o_p(1). 
$$
Now consider the random variable ("instantaneous drift")

$$
D_{\Delta} = \frac{Q_{\Delta}-Q_{0}}{\Delta}
$$

My doubt is: does $D_{\Delta}$ has a finite limit in probability when $\Delta\rightarrow 0$ ? I get lost since I do not know if the residual $Q_{\Delta}-1$ goes to zero in probability faster or slower than $\Delta$.

Comment: What is $o_P(\Delta)$ and $o_P(\sqrt{\Delta})$?

Comment: see, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation

Comment: I can't see why $\int_0^{\Delta}\mu_s\,ds = \mu_0\,\Delta+o_P(\Delta)$ and $ \int_0^{\Delta}\sigma_s\,dWs = \sigma_0\,\sqrt{\Delta}+o_P(\sqrt{\Delta})$.

Comment: Suppose for example that $\sigma_t = \sigma_0$ then $$\mathbb{P}\left[\left| \int_0^{\Delta}\sigma_s\,dW_s - \sigma_0\,\sqrt{\Delta}\right| > \varepsilon\right] \leq\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\,\mathbb{E} \left[\sigma_0\,|W_{\Delta} - \sqrt{\Delta}|\right] = K\,\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{\varepsilon}\rightarrow 0$$ with $K$ a constant that contains combination of error function, $\pi$ and other stuff...

Comment: @AlmostSureUser Protip: insert some spaces into your MathJax. Not only is it more readable that way when editing, also the system inserts a zero-width-non-joiner after 80 characters without any whitespace in between (in comments), and that tends to lead to invalid MathJax.